# Consolidate favourite questions of all sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks, network-profile

I find it frustrating when I see people asking same questions over and over again and I know that I've favoured the same question on one of the Stack Exchange sites. It's just frustrating to know on which.

It would be good to have a consolidated favourites list on profile page where I would see all of my favourites grouped by each SE site. It then wouldn't matter whether I'm on Stack Overflow, Superuser, Photography, Sharepoint... Anywhere. I would be able to see all my favourite questions.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/28335/robert-koritnik?tab=favorites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your favorite questions across the network are already consolidated in the [favorites tab of your network profile on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/28335/robert-koritnik?tab=favorites).